# Iterating map of list for entry

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

This pertains to Java 7.
We have a list of subjects in order of priority `List<SubjectId>`
There is a Map of students to list of subjects opted for - `Map<StudentId,List<SubjectId>>`
The intent is to find the highest priority subject opted by all(common denominator),and return it as map against all students.

Inputs:

```
List<SubjectId>=['1021','1023','1025']

Map<StudentId,List<SubjectId>>={'1',['1025,'1027'];'2',['1021',1025'];'3',['1022','1025']}

Output Map = {'1','1025';'2','1025';'3','1025'}
```

At the moment,we iterate the entire list of students per each subject - composing the output map along the way.
If the subject is found to be missing for any - the map is discarded - and we proceed to the next subject.

Is there a more efficient O(n) approach?

Comment: Don't understand your logic. It the subject has been chosen by all students, why do you need to return a map containing student IDs? Do you just want a list of subjects that has been chosen by all students?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //subjects in order of priority
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1021", "1023", "1025", "1027");

    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("1", Arrays.asList("1021","1025", "1027"));
    map.put("2", Arrays.asList("1021", "1025"));
    map.put("3", Arrays.asList("1023", "1025", "1021"));

    //intersect
    Set<String> intersection = map.values().stream().map(HashSet::new)
        .collect(() -> new HashSet<>(list), Set::retainAll, Set::retainAll);

    //find highest priority
    Optional<String> first = list.stream().filter(intersection::contains).findFirst();
    System.out.println("first = " + first.orElse(""));
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, ALL student must've opted for the subject for it to be chosen. If so, this simplifies the solution a lot.

Are you in need of an output map? Why not just output the resulting subject as the map will always be a repetition of it for all students.

One simple solution I can think of rapidly would be to use the `stream` function available for collections (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) and then use the `filter` function (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) on your map of students + opted subjects to filter out non-chosen subjects out of a list containing all available subjects.

You would also have to create your own predicate which would iterate through all the subjects of each students, which might not be as optimized as you wish for.